# SSIS/SSDT How to insert data from an excel file into database

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

Our source in this case is an Excel file with a lot of data that need to be converted into the right format and type before being inserted into the destination table in SQL Server 2017.

Before, instead of using SSIS, we had a stored procedure to read the excel file using OpenRowset, import the data into a variable table, pass it through a few CTEs to take care of conversion and at last we did an "Insert into/select" to get rid of null/unwanted values.

I wonder what is the right way to do it using SSIS/SSDT?

In SSDT I have created a Package:

- In Connection Manager connection to the excel source and the destination database already exist
- I have placed a DFT in control flow
- in Data Flow inside the DFT, I have configured an Excel Source, passed the output through a few  Data Conversion stages and am ready to insert the data into my OLE DB Destination. I just need to select the rows I need in the last stage of data conversion blocks. I'm not sure How to do that.

Comment: *"I just need to select the rows I need in the last stage of data conversion blocks"* If you want to filter the rows (I assume that's what that sentence means) you want a Conditional Split.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks... indeed, it seems to solve this problem